# Group the data frame rows based on the time difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to Group the data frame rows based on the time difference
Dataframe

```
time name day value
2019-02-05 00:22:00 A sun 55
2019-02-05 00:23:24 A sun 56
2019-02-05 00:32:00 A sun 27
2019-02-05 00:35:00 A sun 27
2019-02-05 01:15:00 A sun 29
2019-02-05 23:15:00 A sun 44
2019-02-05 23:59:00,A,sun,44
2019-02-06 00:05:00 A mon 33
2019-02-06 00:25:00 A mon 22
```

output

```
name start end value day
A   2019-02-05 00:22:00 2019-02-05 00:35:00 27 sun
A   2019-02-05 01:15:00 2019-02-05 01:15:00 29 sun
A   2019-02-05 23:15:00 2019-02-05 23:15:00 44 sun
A   2019-02-05 23:59:00 2019-02-05 23:59:00 44 sun
A   2019-02-06 00:05:00 2019-02-06 00:25:00 22 mon
```

explanation

```
I want to create data frame by grouping the rows if the time difference is <30 mins and minimum value of that group
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
df2 = df.sort_values('time').copy()
rows = []    # Container for output rows
while df2.index.size:
    t0 = df2.iloc[0].time           # "Start" time
    tEnd = t0 + pd.Timedelta('30m') # "End" time
    d0 = t0.normalize()             # Date part
    # Group of source rows: up to the "end" time and same day
    grp = df2[(df2.time <= tEnd) & (df2.time.dt.normalize() == d0)]
    # Compute the output row (and append)
    rows.append([grp.name.iloc[0], grp.time.min(), grp.time.max(),
        grp.value.min(), grp.day.iloc[0]])
    df2.drop(grp.index, inplace=True)    # Delete "processed" rows
# Create result DataFrame
res = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['name', 'start', 'end', 'value', 'day'])
```

Since you want to limit each source group to a single day, additional
condition is necessary, compared to my initial solution. *d0* is the date
part from the first row and rows to be selected must be from the same day.

The result is just as you expected.

I think that no grouping can be used here, because the end of group
depends on the value in first row in the potential group.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo.Thanks for your reply.Your output is combining different days if there is time diff <30.we have to end that for day and start new for other day.

Comment: I have updated the Input and output.Can you check once.